Commutator on a finite-dimensional $\mathcal{H}$ is scalar multiple of an identity
Suppose $A$ and $B$ are operators on a finite-dimensional Hilbert space and suppose that $[A, B] = c I$ for some constant c. Show that $c = 0$.
I have tried approaching the problem using matrices $A, B$ so
\begin{align}
  A_{ik}B_{kj}- B_{il}A_{lj} = c \delta_{ij}
\end{align}
and somehow show that it is the same as $[B,A]$, so the $c$ is forced to be 0.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Observe that, as $\operatorname{tr}(AB)=\operatorname{tr}(BA)$, the trace is linear, and $\operatorname{tr}(I)\neq0$,
$$c\operatorname{tr}(I)=\operatorname{tr}(cI)=\operatorname{tr}([A,B])=\operatorname{tr}(AB)-\operatorname{tr}(BA)=0,$$
implying that $c=0$.
